# Scoping CSS rules

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, portlet, portal

I am currently working on portlet development and I need these portlets to be responsive. I am using Twitter Boostrap 3. It's not that easy to do because medias queries are based on the window width but not on a «container» width...

I was looking for solutions such as « Element Query » ( http://www.xanthir.com/b4PR0 ) but unfortunately it doesn't exist yet.

So I decided to create a custom version of bootstrap which will fit my needs and give more modularity to my portlets so that they can be much more fluid. Here is a [live demo](http://souquet.eu/test/bootstrap/) , which is just a proof of concept (still have little bugs on it but those are mostly fixed on newer versions).

Basically a little javascript snippet test the portlet container width and apply a CSS class to him based on the twitter bootstrap state (`xs` for screen under 768px, `md` for screen between 768px and 992px, etc...)
In the CSS I removed all the medias queries and replaced them with the CSS class corresponding to the « state » for example :

```
@media screen and (max-width : 768px) {
    .module {
        color : red ;
    }
}
```

will be transformed into

```
.portlet-container.xs .module {
    color : red ;
}
```

In my context the « portal » need to import the twitter bootstrap library (It won't be always true but might be sometimes in some use cases) but it can cause trouble with the custom version (I have already fix the double javascript import issue...) for example :

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

will be applied if the screen is over 768px, but it will apply to the portlet navbar even if it's under 768px because nothing override it.

So I am looking for a solution to not apply the original CSS rules to a specific container... I have tried lots of things with `:not()` such as :

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  :not(.portlet-container) .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

which doesn't work (I understand why it doesn't work but i can't see any solution)

I have seen thing such as `.filter(':not(:has(.portlet-container))') ;` in jQuery but I have no idea how to apply it to my case.

I have tried to be as clear as possible but if you don't understand something feel free to ask.

PS : I am using [CSSOM.js](https://github.com/NV/CSSOM) (CSS Object Model) to automate the customization process

Comment: will searching for `;` in the styles for your classes and then inserting a `!important` work?

Comment: nope, because the display:none; is only for screen higher than 768px and for those under 768px it takes its "initial" value which is "block", and i just want my custom version to be exactly the same as the original, just the selector should change...


I had the same idea with the !important at first.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really struggling to understand the actual question. What conditions do you want the `.navbar-toggle` to be `display:none`?

Comment: I want it to be applied everywhere except if `.navbar-toggle` has a parent with the class `.portlet-container` sorry if i was unclear

Comment: In the demo, what combination of screen size, checkboxes and drop down do I need to create the condition. I'm still confused over how to actually use the demo to create the right condition.